# Best Practice: DataBound with loop vs RowDataBound

Tags: asp.net, gridview

If you want to perform an operation on every row of a GridView, you typically would use RowDataBound. But alternatively you could also use DataBound and loop through every row there. Other than saving the foreach line of code in RowDataBound, is there any advantage/disadvantage of either method? (Performance or otherwise?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RowDataBound` is triggered for every row anyway so you don't need an additional loop in the `DataBound`  event. However, since that is micro-optimization the  main difference is that looping the rows with `foreach` will give you just rows with [`DataControlRowType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowtype.aspx) `DataRow` whereas the `RowDataBound` event gives you also other [`RowTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx) as

- **DataRow**:      A data row of a data control. Only DataRow rows can be
  data-bound.
- **EmptyDataRow**: The empty row of a data-bound control. The
  empty row is displayed when the data-bound control has no records to
  display and the EmptyDataTemplate template is not null.
- **Footer**:   A footer row of a data control. Footer rows cannot be data-bound.
- **Header**:  A header row of a data control. Header rows cannot be
  data-bound.
- **Pager**:   A row that displays pager buttons or a pager control.
- **Separator**

So for example, if   you want the footer:

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{  
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

With a `foreach` you get only `DataRows`:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in gridView1.Rows)
{
    // no footer here
}
```

One advantage of the  `DataBound` event is that you know that all rows are already databound at this stage. In `RowDataBound`   you cannot access the controls/text of the second row in the first row. However, if you need this it is probably better to use the underlying `DataSource`(for example a `DataTable`) instead to get the required values(f.e. to aggregate columns).

So the main purpose of `DataBound`  is if you want to trigger something just once right after the grid was databound, not for every `GridViewRow`. Maybe something that is not related to the `GridView` at all.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that using `RowDataBound` holds a distinct advantage for one simple reason: it is going to get executed anyway during databinding. Looping through after the grid is databound adds an unnecessary step.